# How to expose Spark sql results to a web app?

Tags: user-interface, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have used a Azure HDInsight Spark cluster and have performed a simple query using sample data. Now, It is required to display this result in a User Interface. How should I proceed to do this? Are there any open source frameworks to help me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to launch Spark Thrift JDBC/ODBC server and connect your BI tool directly to it. You can find more about how to do this in [Spark guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#distributed-sql-engine)